# Perl Glob everything that doesn't end with zip

Tags: perl, pattern-matching, glob

This is on windows - how do I glob, in perl, all files that don't end with ".zip"?

This is the current code, and for the purpose of this question, is not changeable - all that can be changed is the value of the $pattern variable.

```
my @arr = map { glob( $_ ) } $pattern;
```

As an aside question, what is the purpose of the map function in this code?  It works, but I do not understand it.

Comment: What do you mean by "it works"?

Comment: `map { glob ( $_ ) } $pattern` is equivalent to `glob $pattern`.

Comment: choroba - "works" - the statement returns a list of files to the array, given a pattern, as expected. Is there any point to the map then? I would have written as "@arr = glob $pattern;"

Answer (score 5):

The use of `map` here suggests that one might have multiple patterns to `glob` for. For example

```
my @arr = map { glob( $_ ) } ($pattern1, $pattern2);
```

which would make a list of all the files that match either pattern (possibly repeatedly). Note that you might also populate the array `@arr` using [`readdir`](http://p3rl.org/readdir) builtin.

If you are stuck with the line mentioned, or if you use `readdir`, you may then filter out the results,

```
use File::Basename;
@arr = grep { ! (fileparse $_, '.zip')[2] } @arr;
```

To be even more rigorous you might want to filter out files which actually ARE zip files and not just ones with the name ending in `.zip`:

```
use File::MimeInfo::Magic;
@arr = grep { mimetype($_) ne 'application/zip' } @arr;
```

Answer (score 3):

According to [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html), it's more of a wildcard matching, not a true regex matching.  I've never liked glob anyway (results are not repeatable within the same script, like if the glob is in a loop).

I know you said you couldn't change that glob line (so this might not be possible), but this code does what you're trying to do, using different code though:

```
opendir(DIR, ".") or die $!;
my @nonZipFiles = grep(!/^\.+|\.zip$/, readdir(DIR));
closedir(DIR);

print "$_\n" for @nonZipFiles;
```

Comment: Are you sure that `/[^\.zip]$/` is the regex you are looking for? After all, `[]` denotes a *character class*! Also, inside a character class, `.` is not special and doesn't need escaping. (`(?!\.zip)$` might be better… or `grep {not $_=~/\.zip$/} ...`)

Comment: I think you mean `grep ! /\.zip$/, readdir(DIR)`. And *please* don't use `map` like that - it's an operator not a `for` loop. `print "$_\n" for @nonZipFiles` is fine.

Comment: +1 for `readdir`, -1 for wrong regex. I posted some alternate filters, but didn't include the regex one hoping you'll fix yours

Comment: Sorry, my regex-fu is weak.  I whipped it up fast, and it *worked*, but maybe for the wrong reasons.  I'll make the edit above, and also insure it drops "dot" filenames, esp. "." and "..".